# Notify users about activity on starred (favorite) questions

Tags: feature-request

Right now starring a question does not do much. It's as good as simply bookmarking its link. What I'd like is to be notified of new answers, comments, substantial edits and status changes (reopened, deleted, locked, etc).

Comment: [This was a feature a long time ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52093/), but no longer is.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [question feed](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/2578) below HNQ questions list instead?

Comment: @AkiTanaka I don't think you understand the issue. I would like to get notified about the important changes on the questions that I chose myself, not new questions that most users have upvoted recently.